# PHP stderr not showing in AWS Cloudwatch from ECS Task

Tags: php, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have several scheduled tasks running in AWS ECS Fargate. These tasks are written in php and packaged into a docker image published to an ECR. There are multiple php scripts that are run as tasks. So there is an .sh file with 1 line in it that serves as the entry point for the docker image. An environment variable set for the task definition `SCRIPT_NAME` is there to choose the correct php script to run.

docker image

```
...
...
CMD bash ./run_php_worker.sh
```

run_php_worker.sh

```
php ./worker/$SCRIPT_NAME.php
```

My issue is that the logs from monolog stderr stream handler are not being picked up by the cloudwatch log stream attached to my container definition.

My stream handler is configured like this: `$stream = new StreamHandler('php://stderr');`

The strange part is that if I put an echo statement within my php code, that is picked up and logged by cloudwatch.

I have no idea how to get my monolog logs to print to the console and show in AWS cloudwatch.